# Batch Apex Too many SOQL Queries: 201 on a relationship query

Tags: apex, batch, error, exception

**REQUIREMENT**

**Create a batch apex class that needs to update all of the accounts based on the number of contracts and opportunities for that certain account.**

Here is what I have so far. However, I am receiving "Too many soql queries: 201" error.

```
global class AccountBatchJob implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable{
//Batch Apex
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    Date dateToday = system.today();
    Date lastDayOfTheMonth = dateToday.addMonths(1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1);
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Name, Date_Customer_Churned__c, BillingAddress, BillingCity, BillingCountry, BillingPostalCode, BillingState, (SELECT Id, StartDate, EndDate FROM Contracts WHERE Status = 'Activated'), (SELECT Id, Start_Date_Primary_Quote__c FROM Opportunities WHERE SBQQ__Renewal__c = TRUE AND StageName = 'Closed Lost' AND Start_Date_Primary_Quote__c = THIS_MONTH ORDER BY Start_Date_Primary_Quote__c DESC) FROM Account]);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){
    Date dateToday = system.today();
    Date lastDayOfTheMonth = dateToday.addMonths(1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1);
    //Accounts to update
    List<Account> accToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    for(Account ac : scope){
        //# of Closed Lost Opp for the Month
        ac.No_of_Closed_Lost_Oppty_for_the_Month__c = ac.Opportunities.size();
        Integer newActiveContThisMonth = 0;
        Integer activeContracts = 0;
        for(Contract cnt :ac.Contracts){
            if(cnt.StartDate <= lastDayOfTheMonth && cnt.endDate >= lastDayOfTheMonth){
                activeContracts +=1;
            } else if(cnt.StartDate >= dateToday.toStartofMonth() && cnt.endDate <= lastDayOfTheMonth){
                newActiveContThisMonth +=1;
            }
        }
        //# of Active Contracts
        ac.Active_Contracts__c = activeContracts;
        //# of New Active Contracts for the Month
        ac.New_Active_Contracts_for_the_Month__c = newActiveContThisMonth;
        
        //Date Customer Churned (IF THE ACCOUNT HAS ONE OR MORE CLOSED LOST OPP AND HAS NO ACTIVE CONTRACT)
        if(activeContracts == 0 && newActiveContThisMonth == 0 && ac.Opportunities.size() > 0){
            //THIS IS A TEST (GET ONLY THE LATEST START DATE IN LIST IF THERE ARE ONE OR MORE OPPTY)
            Date sDatePrimaryQuote = ac.Opportunities[0].Start_Date_Primary_Quote__c;
            ac.Date_Customer_Churned__c = sDatePrimaryQuote;
            system.debug('churned customer' + ac.Date_Customer_Churned__c);
        }
        //TEMPORARY CODE ONLY FOR BILLING1 SANDBOX
        if(ac.BillingAddress == null){
            ac.BillingCity = '15 Moore St.';
            ac.BillingCountry = 'Australia';
            ac.BillingPostalCode = '2601';
            ac.BillingState = 'AU';
        }
        accToUpdate.add(ac);
    }
    if(accToUpdate.size() > 0){
        system.debug(accToUpdate.size());
        update accToUpdate;
    }
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    
}
//Schedule this Batch Apex Class
global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx){
    AccountBatchJob abj = new AccountBatchJob();
    database.executeBatch(abj, 200);
}
```

}

As per my situation, I have child relationship query both on Contract and Opportunity objects at the start method. Based from similar problems, I suspect that is the culprit to the error.

Anyone has a workaround to this one? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Never do an Inner query in the start method of the batch class, it causes too many query locators error. The best practice is the query the related records in the execute method with the selective records for the scope.

Comment: @rahulgawale Thanks for the reply.
I thought SOQL queries inside the execute method causes an exception. does it not?

Comment: In the execute method of a batch, you can do SOQL with a max limit of 200. I suspect that this error you are getting because of the Account trigger.

Comment: So should I limit it to 200 only? I execute this through the Apex scheduler

Comment: what do you mean by "So should I limit it to 200 only?"

Comment: I mean on the soql query inside the execute method, should I do LIMIT 200?

Comment: You just need one query in the to execute method to query all the child records, anyway it won't go up to 200. The code you have in the execute method seems good to me. If you still face issue even after doing these changes, there is some problem in the Account trigger. you will need to debug that.